# How to apply styles and text to only one button when clicked instead of all buttons in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, ngfor

So I have an array of links that each have a COPY button that works to copy the text to the clipboard. When clicked, the Copy button is supposed to change its inner text to "Copied!" and the color is also expected to change before a timeout reverts it back to its original state.

The problem is when I click on one button the styles and innerText is applied to all buttons. This is the code:

TS

```
  copyState = { text: 'copy', color: '' };

onClick() {
    this.copyState.text = 'Copied!';
    this.copyState.color = 'hsl(258, 40%, 30%)';

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.copyState.text = 'Copy';
      this.copyState.color = '';
    }, 5000);
  }
```

An external API generates the Links

HTML:

```
  <div class="result" *ngFor="let result of Links; index as i">
    <p class="original_link">{{ result.original_link }}</p>

    <div class="new-link">
      <p>{{ result.short_link }}</p>
      <button 
        [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': copyState.color }"
        [cdkCopyToClipboard]="result.short_link"
        (click)="onClick(i)"
      >
        {{ copyState.text }}
      </button>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider a different approach to solve this scenario.

```
<div class="result" *ngFor="let result of Links; index as i">
  <p class="original_link">{{ result.original_link }}</p>

  <div class="new-link">
    <p>{{ result.short_link }}</p>
    <button
      [ngClass]="{'touched': clickedLink?.short_link === result.short_link}"
      (click)="onClick(i)"
    >
      {{ (clickedLink?.short_link === result.short_link)? 'copied': 'copy' }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the component file :

```
 clickedLink;
  onClick(i) {
    this.clickedLink = this.Links[i];
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.clickedLink = null;
    }, 5000);
  }
```

and in `css` add the following class :

```
.touched {
  background-color: hsl(258, 40%, 30%);
}
```

Here is a working example :

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-efndpc?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: This worked great. I initially did not understand the ternary used there, but I think I do now.  Thanks.

Comment: One thing i dont understand is why the ? is here "(clickedLink?.short_link'"

Comment: This is called optional chaining. Useful when the object can be null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using array for the `copyState.text`. Modify your `Links` array after it gets populated like this

```
Links.forEach(link) {
  link.copyStateColor = '';
  link.copyStateText = 'Copy';
});
```

Now each object in the array has two new properties.Apply it to html like this,

```
  <div class="result" *ngFor="let result of Links; index as i">
    <p class="original_link">{{ result.original_link }}</p>

    <div class="new-link">
      <p>{{ result.[enter image description here][1]short_link }}</p>
      <button [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': result.copyStateColor }" 
              [cdkCopyToClipboard]="result.short_link" 
              (click)="onClick(i)">[enter image description here][1]
        {{ result.copyStateText }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now call your function like this

```
onClick(idx) {
  this.Links[idx].copyStateText = 'Copied!';
  this.Links[idx].copyStateColor = 'hsl(258, 40%, 30%)';

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.Links[idx].copyStateText = 'Copy';
    this.Links[idx].copyStateColor = '';
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only problem I have implementing this solution is : [enter image description here][1].